# How can I Rely on Cassandra, since it doesn't meet my needs, By Itself?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

As we read about Cassandra, before, we decided to choose it as our main database.The most important, useful and special feature which encourage us to choose this db, was **Scalability**, which helps us using Large volumes of data.

But, It seems that, it can not meet our requirements by itself. I asked some questions about our requirement in Stackoverfolw and how we can response them using Cassandra, and the answer was using **alternative tools** on top of Cassandra as **Spark**, **Solr**, **DSE Search** Tools and etc.

Our case is BIG Data Really, but we will have **a large variety of Queries**, too.

With these explanations, is it wise to stay on Cassandra?... Or It's better to switch to another db?

Comment: In my answer below , I didn't  really answer your question. I ve just edited it :)

Comment: exactly ;) Response Time is important for us.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a rant disguised as a question

Comment: No, It's not I believe. Here are many users,who are professional in Cassandra, I want them to tell me, if It's not a good decision to select Cassandra as db,for my project which has too many data with large variety of query.(since it needs additional tools) And also I want others,to share their experiment in this situation. Now, what is wrong with this question???

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is not adequate for ad-hoc queries, so I would recommend that you use Hive on Cassandra, mapping your Cassandra tables to Hive tables, usig the connector: [cassandra_handler_for_hive](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/cassandra_handler_for_hive), ( and then use hive to do joins and conditions on non partition keys)

I should mention that the performance of queries using Hive with Cassandra is not reasonable, (I have had a case where count(*) on a table with 500M records took 1 hour on 4 nodes). As a work around I used to copy the tables in HDFS after that do the computation using data on HDFS, but this is not good solution if you are seeking the fresh data.

Now for your question: To use Cassandra or not, it depends realy on your needs, Cassandra have a good performance in read/write per second record.
If your needs are met with using Hive/Cassandra to do the queries you need, so why not stay on Cassandra?